# On-send for shared mailboxes

Tags: outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=classic) says:

> On-send functionality is only supported for user mailboxes in Outlook on the web, Windows, and Mac. The functionality is not currently supported for the following mailbox types and modes.
>
> - Shared mailboxes

We see that on-send does work with shared mailboxes. Has something changed recently to make the docs inaccurate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ItemSend should work with the SupportsSharedFolders tag: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/supportssharedfolders

But it should not work without that feature. The Documentation should be updated to be more clear.