# Outlook Addin ItemSend for shared mailboxes blocking emails from being sent

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

We have an event based outlook addin and when sending an email from a shared mailbox, the email is not sent and is blocked because the event ItemSend is still being hit even though SupportsSharedFolders is not set in the manifest and the default should be false.

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60549983/on-send-for-shared-mailboxes) it should not work without the SupportsSharedFolders feature enabled.

The event.completed method below is getting ignored too on ItemSend.

`event.completed({ allowEvent: true });`

Office.context.mailbox.initialData contains an error code of 9020 and permissionLevel of 0 as below:

- error:1
- errorCode: 9020
- permissionLevel: 0

The same addin works fine for a user mailbox.

I have tried to just do event.completed in ItemSend, but it still did not work. I expect the ItemSend to not be hit without the SupportsSharedFolders.

Comment: Can you share the platform (Win32/Mac/OWA/New Outlook) where you're experiencing this issue?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT This is happening on OWA.

Comment: It's not a repro for us. Can you please share a video or a sample add-in which can help us investigate it further ?

Comment: Uploaded video here - https://wetransfer.com/downloads/25c01a6d6c04df5961a3cde7894d4bc620230721113828/52cf66